# RemoveAttribute for Filter not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, dom

Am trying to remove filter attribute from DOM

I tried below combinations , But none of them  works in firefox

```
 $('#button').get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter");   //Works in IE8  but not Firefox
 $('#button').get(0).style.removeAttr("filter");   //Not working in IE8 and Firefox
 $('#button').get(0).style.prop("filter","");       //Not working in IE8 and Firefox
 $('#button').get(0).style.prop("filter",none);    //Not working in IE8 and Firefox
```

Getting the below error in firefox

```
 TypeError: $(...).get(...).style.removeAttr is not a function
```

What is the correct way to fix this ?

Comment: style doesn't have attributes or properties.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: $('#button').get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter");   do work in IE ! and the below marked answer did the trick.

Comment: That's those browsers being kind to you, not FF not working.  FF is the only one that handled your code correctly.  The answer below is setting a value for the filter, exactly as you would do with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change style attributes:

```
$('#button').css('filter', 0);
```

Comment: Is there a vanilla Javascript alternative for this please?